# Possible to download and apply stylesheet to angular ngBindHtml?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, node.js

I'm using angular 1.6.
I'm dynamically pulling html from my nodejs server and writing it into a div on the page.

```
<p ng-bind-html="htmlSource"></p>

$scope.htmlSource = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://NOT-MY-SERVER/style.css"><div class='specialcss'></div>';
```

I'm able to display the rendered html fine. But I don't have the right formatting.

Things I need to do

1. Fetch the css, which is not from my server. (Shouldn't encounter cross-site scripting issues with css, right?)
2. Apply it just to the html snippet (and not override my site's default css)
3. Prevent any accompanying javascript in the html from running

Is this possible?

Comment: I've just tried and I don't have any problems... check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/The_Bear/FfT6s/615/)

Comment: Are you using the `$sce` (Strict Contextual Escaping) service?

Comment: @The.Bear Seems $sce.trustAsHtml() is the key, as I see the .css files being downloaded. Is there a way to contain the styles to just within this html so it doesn't affect the rest of my page?

Comment: Also, added a 3rd requirement. Can I prevent/untrust the javascript in the html?

Comment: About apply the style to just one section... css is applied to whole document and I don't see any easy solution (I least for my knowledge). If you can manipulate the server css files, I think is a better approach if you use a unique #id for all css rules a put that unique #id to the div that has the `ng-bind-html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a css stylesheet to an 'html snippet' can be accomplished with [shadow dom](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/shadowdom). However, shadow dom is not supported by all browsers.
It'd look be something like this:

```
var $compile = angular.element('body').injector().get('$compile');
var div = document.createElement('div');
var innerHtml = '<div ng-bind-html='myTemplate.html"/>'
innerHtml+='<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://NOT-MY-SERVER/style.css">';
var shadow = div.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
shadow.innerHTML=innerHTML;
var element = $compile(shadow)(angular.element('body').scope());
angular.element('#parentElementInDomWhereYouWantYourTemplate').append(element)
```

The stylesheet would only cause CORS problems if it's not hosted on your server, or the server that is accessing the stylesheet is not whitelisted.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/JbhGGzi5iqjLiqyalbee)

Comment: Shadow DOM seems promising, but I don't fully understand your code here and can't get it to work. What is myTemplate.html? And could you explain the code a bit more?

Comment: myTemplate.html is whatever your HTML source is. What I'm doing in the code I provided is creating an HTML element, making it the shadow dom root, which is the line with attach shadow, then setting the inner HTML. Since the inner HTML contains an angular directive (ng-bind-html), you need to recompile it for the directive to execute.

Comment: Actually, I looked at your Plunkr and got it to work!